# How to display a background image as hover effect in a CSS Button?

Tags: css, button, background, hover, gradient

I have a CSS3 Gradient button and I'm trying to display a background image (small radial glow to be exact) inside of my button as a hover state. Since my button normal state is already taking up the 'background' tag, when I linked the background image in the hover, the CSS3 gradient effect disappeared when I hovered over it. I tried using background-image tag for the hover, but it didn't work.

Is there a method where I can display the hover background image on top of the normal state when it's hovered?

CSS:

```
    .submit {
    background: rgb(254,219,130); /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(254,219,130,1) 0%, rgba(255,183,50,1) 24%, rgba(255,164,10,1) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(254,219,130,1)), color-stop(24%,rgba(255,183,50,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(255,164,10,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(254,219,130,1) 0%,rgba(255,183,50,1) 24%,rgba(255,164,10,1) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(254,219,130,1) 0%,rgba(255,183,50,1) 24%,rgba(255,164,10,1) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(254,219,130,1) 0%,rgba(255,183,50,1) 24%,rgba(255,164,10,1) 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(254,219,130,1) 0%,rgba(255,183,50,1) 24%,rgba(255,164,10,1) 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#fedb82', endColorstr='#ffa40a',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
}

.submit:hover {
    background-image: url(images/glow.png) center no-repeat;
}
```

HTML:

```
<button class="submit">Button</button>
```

Comment: Can you show us the code you are using right now, in the question or in a fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

Unlike an`input` element, the `button` element can contain other elements, so the easiest way is to simply nest a `span` within the `button` and apply the 'glow' to that element:

```
<button class="submit"><span>Button</span></button>​

.submit:hover span {
    background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
    background: -moz-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(radial, center center, 0px, center center, 100%, color-stop(0%,rgba(255,255,255,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(255,255,255,0)));
    background: -webkit-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%);
    background: -o-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%);
    background: -ms-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%);
    background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#00ffffff',GradientType=1 );
}​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/xJ8Bu/).

I didn't have access to your own image, so I used a [a CSS gradient image generator](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/) as a substitute. Obviously substitute your own relevant image back in.

---

Using a second `background-image`:

With the introduction of CSS3, an element can have multiple backgrounds using a comma-separated list (as with, for example, the `font-face` declaration), which allows for the following:

```
.submit:hover {
    /* IE9 SVG, needs conditional override of 'filter' to 'none' */
    background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
background: -moz-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%), -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(254,219,130,1) 0%, rgba(255,183,50,1) 24%, rgba(255,164,10,1) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(radial, center center, 0px, center center, 100%, color-stop(0%,rgba(255,255,255,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(255,255,255,0))), -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(254,219,130,1)), color-stop(24%,rgba(255,183,50,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(255,164,10,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%), -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(254,219,130,1) 0%,rgba(255,183,50,1) 24%,rgba(255,164,10,1) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%), -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(254,219,130,1) 0%,rgba(255,183,50,1) 24%,rgba(255,164,10,1) 100%); /* Opera 12+ */
    background: -ms-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%), -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(254,219,130,1) 0%,rgba(255,183,50,1) 24%,rgba(255,164,10,1) 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%), linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(254,219,130,1) 0%,rgba(255,183,50,1) 24%,rgba(255,164,10,1) 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#00ffffff',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-8 fallback on horizontal gradient */
}​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/xJ8Bu/1/).

I've not defined a second background under the `filter` property, because I honestly don't know if Microsoft's older browsers would understand the second value, or simply discard the entire rule.

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply. Yes it works but the background only appears where the text is. I wanted it to be part of the button background itself. I tried this method. Hm what else do you think will work?

Comment: *Which* version did you try?

Comment: What do you mean. I thought your reply was only 1 version?

Comment: The first shows the use of a nested `span` within the `button` element, the second shows the use of a second `background-image` (answer edited to clarify).

Comment: I was referring to the first one. The second one however, is not widely supported by browsers so I'm trying to stay away from the CSS3 radial. And secondly, my radial glow in my image is not vertically centered. I was planning to display it aligned bottom showing only half the top. Will defining my button class like <button class="submit button-glow"></button> work? Defining the glow and the button separately?

Comment: Is [this any better](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/xJ8Bu/2/)? Effectively use `display: block` on the nested element, and remove `padding` from the parent. Feel free to substitute your own background in (I specified that I used a CSS background because I don't have access to your image) and position it within the `span` (or other nested element) according to your tastes.